# Wireless HDMI transmitter / receiver for less than 100€

Tags: wireless, hdmi, windows

I have an Intel® Widi compatible smart tv. Unfortunately, Intel withdrew support for that technology in their latest drivers. So their will never be a display driver that support both Intel WiDi and Vulkan correctly.

I can’t connect the computer with an HDMI cable, *(there’s 5m of distance without counting walls)*.

In the meantime, I have a huge problem at connecting Windows 10.1 to any Miracast system *(most of the time, it doesn’t work)*.

So I want to connect my computer to my TV in the same way I would do with an HDMI cable :
I want a device that I would plug on the HDMI output of my computer which would stream video to an another part connected to the TV *(through HDMI)*.

The latency should be low enough to let playing video games through a Bluetooth joystick *(while sending 1080p @ 60Hz with stereo output)*.

[I saw](https://wclink.co/link/658/0/1/1546) [several products](http://www.monoprice.com/Product?seq=1&format=2&p_id=8087). But they all cost more than 100€ and/or are not sold in the € currency.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50756/discussion-between-user2284570-and-zacharee1).

Comment: Are you willing to go with a Used-Like New Item? sold by Amazon or a reputable seller?

Comment: @Jeff : yes, though the only reputed resseller here is le bon coin.

Comment: @Jeff : and [indeed](http://web.archive.org/web/20170619143550/https://www.leboncoin.fr/informatique/1150237579.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnally found one on the right corner : http://web.archive.org/web/20170619143550/https://www.leboncoin.fr/informatique/1150237579.htm